# TypeScript module dependency not exposing source code to dependent

Tags: typescript

I feel like this has to be a solved issue, but for the life of me, I can't find the winning SO post.  Thanks in advance for your direction!

I've got one TypeScript module (we'll call it `my-library`) that serves as a library to others. I'd like other modules to be able to execute the following:

```js
import { client, Payload } from 'my-library'
const payload: Payload = { x: 'y' }
client.send(payload)
```

In the `my-library` module, I've got a top-level file with the following:

```js
export { Payload } from './types/'
export { client } from './client'
```

I'm using rollup.js to output code that can be consumed in various ways.  Here's the package.json configuration, pointing to the output files:

```
  "browser": "dist/index.js",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "module": "lib/index.es6.js",
  "types": "lib/types/index.d.ts",
```

However, when I attempt to import in my dependent repo:

```
import { client, Payload } from 'my-library'
```

... I get an error like the following:

```
Module '"../../../../../Users/my-user/dev/dependent-module/node_modules/my-library/lib/types"' has no exported member 'client'. Did you mean 'Client'?ts(2724)
```

Note that the path ends in `/lib/types`, as if the dependent is only acknowledging the `types` parameter of the package.json.

It looks as if my dependent is only importing types from `my-library`, but ignoring the actual source I'd like to import.  Can anyone tell me how I can get my dependents to import the source code, as well as the typings of `my-library`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works, but is not the prettiest:

```js
import { Payload } from 'my-library'
import { client } from 'my-library/lib/client'
const payload: Payload = { x: 'y' }
client.send(payload)
```

I've broken the `client`'s import into a different line, and explicitly dug into the module's directories to the `client`'s definition.  This builds, but I wish it wasn't necessary.

If anyone has a better idea, I'm all ears.